# Infinit Scroll - não traz todos os dados do BD

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli, while, ciclo-infinito

estou tentando implementar um infinit scroll no meu projeto, porém estou com dificuldade em resolver esse problema

a conexão está perfeira e estou recebendo as informações do BD, porém o código só mostra uma entrada, o que devo alterar para resolver isso?

Código index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>jQuery Infinite Scroll</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var start = 0;
            var working = false;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "data.php?start="+start,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: '',
                            success: function(r) {
                                    r = JSON.parse(r)
                                    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                                            $('body').append("<div><h1>"+r[i].videoName+"</h1><h2>Video View: "+r[i].videoViews+"</h2></div>")
                                    }
                                    start += 6;
                            },
                            error: function(r) {
                                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                            }
                    })
            })
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() + 1 >= $('body').height() - $(window).height()) {
                            if (working == false) {
                                    working = true;
                                    $.ajax({
                                            type: "GET",
                                            url: "data.php?start="+start,
                                            processData: false,
                                            contentType: "application/json",
                                            data: '',
                                            success: function(r) {
                                                    r = JSON.parse(r)
                                                    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                                                            $('body').append("<div><h1>"+r[i].videoName+"</h1><h2>Video View: "+r[i].videoViews+"</h2></div>")
                                                    }
                                                    start += 6;
                                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                                            working = false;
                                                    }, 4000)
                                            },
                                            error: function(r) {
                                                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                                            }
                                    });
                            }
                    }
            })
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Código data.php:

```
<?php

class Video {
    public $videoName = "";
    public $videoViews = "";

    public function __construct($videoName, $videoViews) {
            $this->videoName = $videoName;
            $this->videoViews = $videoViews;
    }
}
$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***") or die("Erro 001 - Conection lost");
if ($conectar->connect_errno) {
     echo "Falha ao conectar com o mysql: (" . $conectar->connect_errno . ") " . $conectar->connect_error;
}

$start = $_GET['start'];
$data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);
while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){


$possibleVideos = array(
     new Video($linhas['nome'],$linhas['tempo']),
    );

    }

for ($i = $start; $i < $start+6; $i++) {
    if ($i < count($possibleVideos)) {
            array_push($data, $possibleVideos[$i]);
    }
}

//echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Por que não utilizar [OFFSET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) do `MySQL` ou `SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, 5;`?

Comment: não sei fazer, fui aprendendo em um tutorial até chegar nisso

Comment: Tente com o código `SELECT ...` que postei e veja se resolve algo. Com ele você **não** irá precisar do `for ($i = $start; $i < $start+6; $i++) ...`

Comment: infelizmente não deu certo, substituindo o SELECT... e removendo o for ($i... a pagina fica em branco, não traz nenhum registro

Comment: É você você não está atribuindo os valores na variável `$date`. Exemplo completo: https://pastebin.com/HJ37Rram

Comment: ele está trazendo a quantidade de entradas, mas não traz as informações, todos os registros estão listados como undefined

Comment: Adicione `console.log(r);` antes de `r = JSON.parse(r)` e verifique na aba `Console` (F12) qual o resultado. Alterei meu código no link acima.

Comment: Sensacional amigo, funciona perfeitamente, muitíssimo obrigado!

Comment: Me deparei com um problema quando tentei implementar o código ao projeto, o problema é que as entradas carregam no fim da página e não dentro da <div class="row">  que o scrypt se encontra... alguma ideia que possa me ajuda? @ValdeirPsr

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll para isso, basta criar a div aonde você quer colocar o elemento,atribuir um id a ela e depois fazer o seguinte: $('#sua-div').append(resultado)

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o [**OFFSET**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) ou o [**LIMIT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) para capturar a partir de um determinado registro. Ex:

```
/* Dessa forma você irá capturar os 5 primeiros registros */
SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 5;

/* Dessa forma você irá capturar os 5 primeiros registros após o décimo registro */
SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10;

/* Mesma coisa que o item acima */
SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 10, 5;
```

Como sua variável `$start` sempre vai receber um `offset`, então basta utilizar esse modo. Isso vai economizar recursos do servidor.

> Imagina se você tivesse mais *10.000* posts. Ter que retornar *10.000* várias vezes e depois pegar apenas os últimos. Agora imagina *1.000* pessoas acessando teu site ao mesmo tempo...

**Código completo e refatorado:**

```
<?php

$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***") or die("Falha ao conectar com o mysql: (" . $conectar->connect_errno . ") " . $conectar->connect_error);

/* Verifica se o parâmetro `start` existe, caso não exista adiciona 0 à variável */
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, 5";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);

if ( $error = mysqli_error($conectar) ) {
    die( $error );
}

while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $data[] = array(
        "videoName" => $linhas['nome'],
        "videoViews" => $linhas['tempo']
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

Para adicionar esses dados dentro da `div.row`, é necessário substituir `$('body').append()` por `$('div.row').append()`.

Mas isso não é recomendado. Caso você tenha mais de uma `div` com a classe `row`, o texto será adicionado em todas elas. O ideal é você sempre utilizar o atributo `id` para isso. Ex:

**Html:**

```
<div id="videos" class="row"></div>
```

**Js:**

```
$('#videos').append(...);
```

**Exemplo completo e refatorado:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery Infinite Scroll</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="videos" class="row"></div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let start = 0;
            let working = false;

            $(document).ready(function() {
                loadData();
            })

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                    loadData();
                }
            })

            function loadData() {
                if (working == false) {                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "index3.php",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: {start: start},
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            working = true;
                        },
                        success: function(r) {
                            r = JSON.parse(r)

                            /* Percorre todos os valores que estão no `array` r */
                            for (data of r) {
                                $('#videos').append("<div><h1>"+data.videoName+"</h1><h2>Video View: "+data.videoViews+"</h2></div>")
                            }

                            working = false;

                            start += 6;
                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                            console.log("Something went wrong!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fiz as alterações, o arquivo data.php está ok, mas a página index, após a rolagem só carrega outras entragas uma vez, mesmo usando o PgUp e PgDn do teclado.

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll Alterei o `html` da minha resposta. Removi o `setTimeout` e a forma como é verificado se o usuário está no final da página.